# The Bootstrap carousel on my homepages doesnt work as expected

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, frontend, angular8

I am trying to build an image carousel using bootstrap 4. However the images doesnt slide the way it should. The cursor to change the slide is not working. The slides repeats the images when you try to go the next slide.

This is the link to the project [alabamarket.com](https://alabamarket.com)
to see the strange behaviour

Here is the code I have written

```
 <div class="col-md-8 hide">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/award-alaba.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/5.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The cursers to change the slide it is not working but I am not getting your problem here because you are saying the images do not slide how they should.
Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @nideba The cursor to change the slide is not working. The slides repeats the images when you try to go the next slide whne you click the indicator

Comment: @lamlimo Did you try to copy the code form bootstrap and then there to paste and only to test if it works everything ok ?

Comment: @nideba I did that! it still didnt workk

Comment: @lamlimo How did you install the bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange behaviour testing your site

> open dev tools in chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I) and search in source panel the div `<div _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" class="carousel-inner">`
>   press right mouse on it and choose "edit html", then  copy all the content(ctrl-A , ctrl-C).

ok.. now clear content (ctrl-A+suppr) and past your content..(I know "you pasted what you copied") this still not working

... now edit again html this div ,clear content (ctrl-A+suppr)  but this time paste the content bellow (working code) ... it's works as expected,

However it is the same code, except that it was copied in notepad.

Maybe a special character is present in your source code, following a copy / paste?

> WORKING CODE

```
<div _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" class="carousel-inner">

    <div _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" class="carousel-item active">
       <img _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" alt="First slide" class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" class="carousel-item">
       <img _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" alt="Second slide" class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" class="carousel-item">
       <img _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" alt="Third slide" class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/award-alaba.jpg">
    </div>

    <div _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" class="carousel-item">
       <img _ngcontent-wfo-c3="" alt="Third slide" class="d-block w-100" src="assets/sliders/5.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```